# Mix of HTML table and PrimeFaces p:datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

When I try to put in plain HTML table in a PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` the output of the resulting table becomes weird and overlapped.

The code I tried is:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="509" style="border-collapse: collapse;width:382pt">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="19" style="height:14.4pt">
      <p:dataTable>
        <p:column>
          <table>
            <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
          </table>
        </p:column>
      </p:datatable>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why you are doing this? you can even implement nested table in PrimeFaces

Comment: well actually the content is get from email content from user, is there any way convert it?

Comment: Didn't get you, What you are trying to do?

Comment: I want <table><tr>abc</tr></table>  to be shown in primeface Datatable.
The value is retrieved from db and it WAS keyed in by user.